# Steam Market Image API

Tags: php, json, decode, steam-web-api

I got a new problem while working on my project.

I want to decode this (what I tried until now):

```
$items = array($_POST['eingabe']);      
$strs = file_get_contents("https://open-market.io/api/search/?name=$items&appID=730&limit=5");
$json = json_decode($strs, true);
$picimage = $json['results'][0]['image'];
echo '<a class="test1">' . $picimage . '</a></div></br>';
```

I really don't know what I did wrong. Can someone please show me my mistake?

example for json:

https://open-market.io/api/search/?name=Chroma%20Case&appID=730&limit=5

Comment: What is in your request url? can you echo "https://open-market.io/api/search/?name=$items&appID=730&limit=5"

Comment: For example: https://open-market.io/api/search/?name=Chroma%20Case&appID=730&limit=5

Comment: your code works fine on myside, I used "counter" as the name param. You need to look at whats in $items. FYI, you should remove your appID be careful about posting confidential info.

Comment: Thats not a confidential info :) it's the appID of Counter Strike Global Offensive .... so I think it dont matter.

Comment: cool just checking ;), posted an answer that solves your problem its because your referencing an array as a string.

Comment: the base64 of image is invalid ? (tried few mime type, but nothing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implode your array and urlencode it.

```js
<?php
$items = array('counter','age');
$strs = file_get_contents("https://open-market.io/api/search/?name=".urlencode(implode($items,','))."&appID=730&limit=5");
$json = json_decode($strs, true);
$picimage = $json['results'][0]['image'];
echo '<a class="test1"> ' . $picimage . "</a></div></br>";
```

Comment: Thank you really much. You are my hero :D